# ¿Como cambiar todos los elementos de una columna en un DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

estoy haciendo un trabajo de programación y cree un DataFrame con la información. Esta se encontraba en una biblioteca dentro de otro dataframe (Archivo['serie'])
use una función para transformar cada uno de mis dataframes para que tengan los datos que necesito

```
def Create_Data_Frame(archivo):
    Archivo = pd.DataFrame(archivo)
    Archivo = Archivo['serie']
    Organized = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['fecha', 'valor'])
    #for a in Archivo['fecha']
    for obj in Archivo:
        for item in obj:
            Organized = Organized.append(item, ignore_index=True)
    return Organized


Dolar = Create_Data_Frame(dolar)
Tasa =  Create_Data_Frame(tasa)
Libra = Create_Data_Frame(libra)
IPC = Create_Data_Frame(ipc)
```

El problema es que cuando imprimo uno de los DataFrames las fechas de la columna salen de la siguiente manera:

"dd-mm-yyyyT03:00:00"

¿Que puedo hacer para cambiar cada una y que queden de la forma?

"dd-mm-yyyy"
Intente hacer un for que cambie cada una de las fechas pero esto hace que surja el mensaje:

> SettingWithCopyWarning

Gracias por su ayuda y quedo atenta a su respuesta